# Link CMake source directory to Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake

I have a C# project set up to be generated from CMake, I then do the actual development work in Visual Studio. CMake creates the .csproj file (and the .sln file) in a build directory which is next to the source directory, and all source files are then included via links in the .csproj file. This works fine to allow me to build the project, but I hit an issue with adding new components to the project. Because there is a lot of boilerplate that gets added from e.g. a WPF window (across multiple files), I want to use the Add New Item option from within VS to generate the new files. However, VS insists on creating the new files in the build tree, and I then have to copy them back over to the source folder before adding them to my CMakeLists.txt. Is there any way to tell Visual Studio that I want to use a folder outside of the .csproj directory to hold my source files, rather than just linking in all the individual files to appear to be in the build tree? I am using VS2019.

Comment: This workflow won't work (at least the way we set up the Visual Studio projects using cmake at work): The "Add Item" functionality modifies your local Visual Studio project files which means if you're lucky, nobody will see your changes, since this project is not part of the tracked files in the repository. If you're unlucky you'll pull changes that modify one of the `CMakeLists.txt` resulting in VS using cmake to regenerate some projects and your changes are gone... You'll need to modify the `CMakeLists.txt` and then build `ZERO_CHECK` to update the projects...

Comment: As alternative to building `ZERO_CHECK` you could also use the command line to pass the binary directory as the only parameter to `cmake`; One way or another cmake will probably notify you of a modification to the project by an external tool and you'll need to reload some of your projects, if not the entire solution.

Comment: @fabian - I am aware that Add Item won't touch my CMakeLists.txt, but I just want to use it for all the boilerplate for e.g. a WPF Window (.xaml/.xaml.cs etc.). Then I will modify CMakeLists.txt manually to include the newly generated files (and set their xaml status etc.) and then rerun CMake to replace the .csproj with the files added via CMake. I don't think that part can be solved. What I want is simply to make it so that the Add Item will put the boilerplate files in the source directory (out of tree), so I don't have to copy them into it before doing that part.